# In Ruby, how do I replace the question mark character in a string?

Tags: ruby, string, uri, substitution

In Ruby, I have:

```
require 'uri'
foo = "et tu, brutus?"
bar = URI.encode(foo)      # => "et%20tu,%20brutus?"
```

I'm trying to get bar to equal "et%20tu,%20brutus%3f" ("?" replaced with "%3F")  When I try to add this:

```
bar["?"] = "%3f"
```

the "?" matches everything, and I get

```
=> "%3f"
```

I've tried

```
bar["\?"]
bar['?']
bar["/[?]"]
bar["/[\?]"]
```

And a few other things, none of which work.

Comment: Out of curiosity, did you try `bar["\\?"]`?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`require 'cgi'` and call `CGI.escape`

Answer (score 4):

Here's a sample irb session:

```
irb(main):001:0> x = "geo?"

=> "geo?"

irb(main):002:0> x.sub!("?","a")

=> "geoa"

irb(main):003:0>
```

However, sub will only replace the first character. If you want to replace all the question marks in a string, use the `gsub` method like this:

```
str.gsub!("?","replacement")
```

Comment: Thanks.  This and CGI.escape both work nicely.  I went with this one, though.  (Fewer requires.)

Comment: @geo, although your answer is technically correct and to Olie's point,  he should really use CGI.escape.

Comment: Yes, but this way his knowledge of the language increases.

Answer (score 4):

There is only one good way to do this right now in Ruby:

```
require "addressable/uri"
Addressable::URI.encode_component(
  "et tu, brutus?",
  Addressable::URI::CharacterClasses::PATH
)
# => "et%20tu,%20brutus%3F"
```

But if you're doing stuff with URIs you should really be using [Addressable](https://github.com/sporkmonger/addressable) anyways.

```
sudo gem install addressable
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know which characters you accept, you can remove those that don't match.

```
accepted_chars = 'A-z0-9\s,'
foo = "et tu, brutus?"
bar = foo.gsub(/[^#{accepted_chars}]/, '')
```

Answer (score 0):

`URI.escape` accepts the optional parameter to tell which characters you want to escape. It overrides defaults so you'll have to call it twice.

```
> URI.escape URI.escape("et tu, brutus?"), "?"
=> "et%20tu,%20brutus%3F"
```